# Cannot change email in Profile

Tags: support, bug, profile-page, email

[image: Error message]

I'm getting this error when I try to change my email.  The email I'm trying to change to has previously been registered to SE, but I removed that login recently.  That email is no longer (or shouldn't be) associated with and SE account.

What's going on?

Comment: There are still two emails associated with your other account..

Comment: Really?  I thought I removed that one from my other account.  \*checking again\*

Comment: Under 'My Logins' I only see 1.

Comment: Look under preferences instead of my logins.

Comment: That email address does not appear in preferences.

Comment: Come to chat, lets see if we can figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there was a bug in the system.

I needed to change my email in the secondary account to something new (instead of blank), then everything worked like it should.

INFINITE THANKS TO @Seth.  You're the man, man.